# Alternative of file_get_contents function

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to get json data from https://nepse-data-api.herokuapp.com/data/todaysprice.

I use `file_get_contents()` function but I got below error msg

> Message: require(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Now my problem is I am using shared hosting so `allow_url_fopen = 1` is not possible.

How can I get the data from above url.

In localhost this code is working properly, Here is my code

```
$url = 'https://nepse-data-api.herokuapp.com/data/todaysprice'; 
$raw = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($raw);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: You can use cURL or sockets.

Comment: Also see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart#prerequisites

Comment: You can use CURL,It's very simple. Check my answer for more details.

Comment: to consume an api, use an http client - netiher curl, nor sockets. this will let you to write a readable and understandable code. or roll one on top of that tools. `file_get_contents` might work on that situation - but do not do it. e.g. give a chance to `guzzlehhtp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you’re using PHP to retrieve data from a certain server you probably came across the problem that it may work for you but a client complained about lots of errors. It’s pretty likely that you’ve relied on the fact that `allow_url_fopen` is set to true. This way you can put pretty much anything – local path or a URL – into function calls like `include` or maybe `simplexml_load_file`.

If you’d like to get around this problem you can advice your client to make the necessary changes in his `php.ini` file. Most of the time this isn’t an option because the hosting company decided to disable this feature for security reasons. Since almost everybody got cURL installed we can use this to retrieve data from another web server.

**Implementation**

I’ll present a wrapper that helps you loading an XML file. It uses `simplexml_load_file` if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. If this feature is disabled it employs `simplexml_load_string` and cURL. If none of this works we’ll throw an exception because we weren’t able to load the data.

```
class XMLWrapper {

  public function loadXML($url) {
    if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen') == true) {
      return $this->load_fopen($url);
    } else if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
      return $this->load_curl($url);
    } else {
      // Enable 'allow_url_fopen' or install cURL.
      throw new Exception("Can't load data.");
    }
  }

  private function load_fopen($url) {
    return simplexml_load_file($url);
  }

  private function load_curl($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return simplexml_load_string($result);
  }

}

//For Json

class JsonWrapper {

  public function loadJSON($url) {
    if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen') == true) {
      return $this->load_fopen($url);
    } else if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
      return $this->load_curl($url);
    } else {
      // Enable 'allow_url_fopen' or install cURL.
      throw new Exception("Can't load data.");
    }
  }

  private function load_fopen($url) {
    $raw = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($raw);
    return $data;
  }

  private function load_curl($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $data = json_decode($result);
    return $data;
  }

}
```

The code is pretty simple, create an instance of the given class and call the `loadXML` method. It’ll call the `right` private method which finally loads the XML. Loading some XML is just an example, you can use this technique with e.g. `include` or `require` too.

Comment: Think they are fetching JSON not XML.

Comment: @NigelRen Updated Answer, added new class for json.